# Multiple Connection on mongoengine.. Give me some examples~

Tags: python, django, database-connection, mongoengine, mlab

I'm using mongoengine with django.

in my project web application, I need to connect at least two servers: one that is local for session, another connecting to mongolab (mongodb hosting service company).

So.. I need to connect localhost for session.. while connecting to another server in distance.

How can I implement multiple connections on mongoengine?

give me some examples please.

---

```
a Web application   --- connecting ---> localhost for session
                    --- connecting ---> mongolab for application database
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mongoengine dev branch. 
Support multiple dbconnection with alias. https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/commit/8d2bc444bb64265f78f5bf716f773742dddd56c1

See this tests.

https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/dev/tests/document.py#L2584

Answer (score 1):

Depending on [mongoengine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases), to use multiple databases you can use `connect()` and provide an *alias* name for the connection. In the background this uses `register_connection()` to store the data and you can register all aliases up front if required.

```
connect(alias='user-db-alias', db='user-db')
connect(alias='book-db-alias', db='book-db')
connect(alias='users-books-db-alias', db='users-books-db')

class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

    meta = {'db_alias': 'user-db-alias'}

class Book(Document):
    name = StringField()

    meta = {'db_alias': 'book-db-alias'}

class AuthorBooks(Document):
    author = ReferenceField(User)
    book = ReferenceField(Book)

    meta = {'db_alias': 'users-books-db-alias'}
```

You can also use `switch_db()` method.

The function disconnect() can be used to disconnect a particular connection. This can be used to change a connection globally:

```
from mongoengine import connect, disconnect
connect('a_db', alias='db1')

class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    meta = {'db_alias': 'db1'}

disconnect(alias='db1')

connect('another_db', alias='db1')
```